# SagePay Server Integration - PayPal IPN

Tags: paypal, server, integration, paypal-ipn, opayo

My issue is that PayPal is performing security checks on their end, but marking the order as pending. This means that I am getting an OK status from the notification response on SagePay, but am unable to hold the order from being sent to the warehouse which the client has requested.

The documentation I have taken a look at is https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/25046/download-document/SERVER_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf and I have attempted to speak with SagePay directly.

Please, could someone let me know whether they have ever integrated the PayPal IPN with the SagePay server integration before?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sage Pay doesn't support Paypal IPN. Sage Pay's Payment integration is a one shot thing - once the transaction is done, it's done - it exists in either an authorised or declined state, and is immune to any further changes.

Your best bet might be to implement IPN outside of Sage Pay. You could hold all Paypal orders by default, and then wait for notifications from PayPal to indicate they are cleared to ship.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359288/sagepay-seems-to-be-using-stack-overflow-for-all-support